# Pascal Debian Jessie TryGetData not working

Tags: freepascal

when I Try in Pascal under Debian Jessie

```
 TStringObjectMap2 = class  
  private 
    type
    TStrObjMap = class(specialize TFPGMap<string, THostHandler>);
  private
    FObjects: TStrObjMap;
    FDefaultObject: THostHandler;
    FFreeObjects: boolean;

    function GetObject(const AKey: string): THostHandler;
    procedure SetDefault(AValue: THostHandler);
    procedure SetObject(const AKey: string; AValue: THostHandler);
  public
    constructor Create(FreeObjects: boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure RemoveHandler(const AKey: string);
    function TryGetObject(const AKey: string; out AObject: THostHandler): boolean;

    property DefaultObject: THostHandler read FDefaultObject write SetDefault;
    property Objects[const AKey: string]: THostHandler read GetObject write SetObject; default;

  end;
```

the Line

```
Result := FObjects.TryGetData(AKey, AObject);
```

can not compiled

But under Win 10 there is no problem.

Whats going wrong?

Comment: Which compiler are you using on both platforms?

Comment: @mxmissile: Lazarus 1.2.4

Comment: Isn't that old? Anyway, show the error you get.